# Argument to function must match object shape

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function `test` that accepts an argument of type `T` and returns something of type `T`

`T` has the following requirements:

it's an object with 2 properties: `a = string`, `b = number | undefined`

```js
function test<T extends { a: string, b?: number }>(arg: T) {
  arg.b = 123;
  return arg;
}

type A = { a: string, b?: number };
const a: A = { a: "1" };
test(a)

type B = { a: string, b?: number, c: string };
const b: B = { a: "1", c: "hello" };
test(b)

type C = { a: string, c: string };
const c: C = { a: "1", c: "hello" };
test(c) // ok, but I want this to raise an error because it doesn't have the property `b?: number`
```

The reason behind my requirement is that the return value of `test` will be serialized, saved in a database and later retrieved from the database.

After the record has been retrieved from the database it will be parsed with [zod#strict](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#strict) which will raise an error because `c` was saved with `c.b = 123` but `b` is not a valid property on `C`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether `b` is in the `T` and if it is then you type the `arg` as `T`, otherwise `never`:

```
function test<T extends { a: string; b?: number }>(
  arg: 'b' extends keyof T ? T : never,
) {}
```

Testing:

```
type A = { a: string; b?: number };
const a: A = { a: '1' };
test(a);

type B = { a: string; b?: number; c: string };
const b: B = { a: '1', c: 'hello' };
test(b);

type C = { a: string; c: string };
const c: C = { a: '1', c: 'hello' };
test(c); // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCqJQD1TABM1EBvRAQwC5EMAnGMAcwG5EAjAfjrBAC2nFA0QBfAHwAKAFCJqDFnQDknZXkIoSZANYoAnnGCJc3E4j4oAbiIA0MgJQU5ClgDpOiALyIAjACYAZjYXBhQoEAYkKkUQsRkZKH0ABxREAEFvCmo6RmZ2Ll5EfiERcRCIBAwcjKzKWkRlX3UxENQMKSoHEMSUtIAhOpq81g4ePkFhBg4IXKgmVnKZSrBqzjpBn3qVZttEWcaACxQAGxO4Frb0KClOboSk1MQAYSGGkYKDj6WV6oPXrY1JrKPYHZTHM4XJbtG4QbqIAD0CLwDAYcAYQA)

Comment: Bruh wtf. I was sitting over this for 6 hours last night and you solve this within 20 nanoseconds. Thanks, totally makes sense!!! (edit: there is cooldown for accepting answer, will do in ~7 min)